# Put List into jQuery script MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I use jQuery UI Autocomplete.
Part of script is:

```
$("input[data-autocomplete]").each(function () {
var availableTags = ["first", "second"];
```

And it works -autocomplete with "first" and "second"

Now i want to assign avalibleTags dinamicly like something like:

```
var availableTags = @Viewbag.Something
```

or

```
var availableTags = @Url.Action('Tags","Home")
```

It is possible? How to do it in a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
   var MyTags =  $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Tags","Home")' function (MyList) {
       // Do something with List
       // var avaliableTags = MyList;
    }); 
 });
 </script>
```

(This uses JQuery)

Would work. Where the action is in controller like:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult Tags()
    {
        var MyList == YOUR TAGS
        return Json(MyList , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);        
    }
```

Note, the use of the attribute and JSON to allow Javascript communication.

Edit: woops, used key words.

Comment: I did that and it doesnt work. Html looks like:  'var availableTags = $.getJSON('/Ideas/GetTags/') ;' Get Tags looks like:         '[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public JsonResult GetTags ()
        { 
            return Json(_configurationRepository.GetTags(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }' Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Sorry, the first bit is Javascript not HTML. Ill change my answer to be more clear. You will need to use List to set what ever it is you wish to do with it.

Comment: That syntax ' $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Tags","Home")' function (List) {'

Comment: The section now wrapped in script tags is Javascript. You will need to be setting your auto complete in the same manner. except here you can access the database etc via the controller action, to obtain possible tags - Accidently used the key word. please see revised code(not using the word List.)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just make sure to JSON encode it:

```
var availableTags = @Json.Encode(ViewBag.Something);
```

and since I hate ViewBag and recommend you always using view models and strongly typed views:

```
var availableTags = @Json.Encode(Model.Something);
```

This assumes that `Something` is an array of strings property on your view model so that when the page is rendered you will get:

```
var availableTags = ["first", "second"];
```

and will be able to use it with the autocomplete plugin.